# ProgresDialog doesn't show up

Tags: android

```
public Context ctx;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.ctx = this;
            //another code......)

        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wyslij_zapytanie_ofertowe);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
                try {   
                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("dasdda@gmail.com", "ddx");
                    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                            "This is Body",   
                            "staxxxowe@gmail.com",   
                            "xxxyk@gmail.com");   
                  dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {   
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } 
            }
        });
```

I try also instead ctx put ClassName.class and also doesn't work. Any one have idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your problem is that you call `dialog.dismiss();` "immediately" after you call `dialog.show()` and this may cause this "not showing" efect.

```
dialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      dialog.dismiss();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably getting dismissed even before it gets created since only a few lines later you call `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: You are right. When I delete dialog.dismiss() it shows. How to show dialog for eg. 1 sec and then call dismiss() method?

Comment: you cant, the dialog needs time to get created and if its getting dismissed before that time then it wont be fully created. If its something that gets executed that quick then you really dont need a progress dialog since you have `5 seconds` before the OS throws a `ANR` error, If you really want to show a dialog you can use a handler with a sew seconds delay before executing the code so the dialog has time to show. Progress dialog are used for long running operations

Comment: ok. I thought that if someone click 'Send' and application seems to be not-responding even for couple seconds, it could be annoying

Comment: if thats the case you can always put it in another thread and not worry about it